# Корень в слове "шел"

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Какой корень в словах "шел", "шла", "шли"? Неужели одна буква Ш?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Корень Ше/Ш с беглой гласной Е**.
Сравните: пришелец-пришлый.

ЗЫ Корня из одного согласного звука в русском не бывает. Минимальный корень - "У" в словах "обувь"-"обуваться"-"разутый". Хотя он тоже является рефлексом очень непростых фонетических преобразований, но настолько древних, что их можно не принимать в расчет.

По еще более смелой гипотезе И/ИД (в "идти") и Ш/ШЕ (в "шел") тоже являются разными ступенями еще более древнего корневого чередования, т.е. их тоже надлежит, дескать, считать одним коренем. Но это уже не для простых умов.

Answer (score 1):

Да, одна буква Ш. Такое бывает в русском языке. Хотя некоторые сомнения у меня имеются. Например, в слове *шедший* — корень "ше". Высказывается мнение, что здесь наличествует чередование ш/ше. Но такое чередование с беглой гласной должно встречаться и в других словах, а я таких слов не припомню.

Comment: Вы не знаете о существовании в русском языке беглых гласных?
Или вам обязательно надо с Ш?
Шить-швец-шевческий.

Answer (score 0):

Идущий передвигается шагом. Шаг как одно движение ногой (в основном значении слова *шаг*) имеет также значение сопутствующего этому действию звука. На стыке «шипящих» слов — шаг, шум, шелест, шорох, — существует ряд «*шёл, шла, шло, шли*». Поскольку он, мягко говоря, не длиннее, чем ряды и колонны от указанных этих других, где в корне видим почти все возможные гласные, можно отбросить вариант с одной беглой и предположить,что корень ***ш*** существует. Тем более, что эта беглая — по большей части находится в бегах.

Версия «беглой гласной» должна говорить о существовании корня ***шл/шёл***.